# Pthreads based program crashing on MacOS doesn't crash on Linux

Tags: pthreads

I have a pthreads based program with 3 threads that crashes on MacOS (Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0) within a few seconds. I was expecting the same behavior on Linux. But the program doesn't crash on Linux. I am left speculating if Linux has a different thread scheduling policy or if it is something else. Any pointers appreciated.

This is the program. If I don't use pthread mutex lock in the printer thread, it is supposed to crash because the linked list is left in an inconsistent state.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include "list.h"

#define RANGE_MIN 1
#define RANGE_MAX 10

pthread_t tid[3];

list_t list;

pthread_mutex_t queue_lock;

/* Return a uniformly random number in the range [low,high]. */
int random_range (unsigned const low, unsigned const high)
{
  unsigned const range = high - low + 1;
  return low + (int) (((double) range) * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
}
/*
 * consumer thread function
 */
void* consumer(void *arg)
{
        static int val = 0;
        while (1) {
                //sleep(1);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);
                while (list.total_elem > 0)
                    consume_and_delete(&list);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
        }
}

void *producer(void *arg)
{
        while (1) {
                //sleep(1);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);
            while (list.total_elem < 10)
                add_to_list(&list, random_range(RANGE_MIN, RANGE_MAX));
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
        }
}

/*
 * printer thread function
 */
void* printer(void *arg)
{       
        while (1) {
                
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);  //lines deliberately commented out to show the crash
                print_list(&list);
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret;

        if (pthread_mutex_init(&queue_lock, NULL) != 0) {
                printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
                return 1;
        }


    ret = pthread_create(&(tid[1]), NULL, &consumer, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
    }
    ret = pthread_create(&(tid[0]), NULL, &producer, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
    }
    ret = pthread_create(&(tid[2]), NULL, &printer, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(ret));
        }

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&queue_lock);

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the code for list.h and list.c

```
ifndef __LIST_H__
#define __LIST_H__

typedef struct node_ {
    int num;
    struct node_ *next;
} node_t;

typedef struct list_ {
    int total_elem;
    node_t *head;
} list_t;

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void add_to_list(list_t *list, int num);
node_t *allocate_new(int num);
void consume_and_delete(list_t *list);
void print_list(list_t *list);

#endif
```

list.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

void add_to_list(list_t *list, int val)
{
        node_t *tmp;
        node_t *new;

    new = allocate_new(val);
    if (!new) {
        printf("%s: allocation failure \n", __FUNCTION__);
    }

        printf("%s: Enqueueing %d\n", __FUNCTION__, new->num);

        if (!list) {
                return;
        }

        if (!list->head) {
                list->total_elem++;
                list->head = new;
                return;
        }

        tmp = list->head;
        while (tmp->next) {
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = new;
        list->total_elem++;
}
node_t *allocate_new(int num)
{
        node_t *tmp;

        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (!tmp) {
                printf("%s: failed in malloc\n", __FUNCTION__);
                return NULL;
        }
        tmp->num = num;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        return tmp;
}
/* reads from the front of the queue and deletes the element
 */
void consume_and_delete(list_t *list)
{
        node_t *tmp, *next;

        if (!list->head) {
                return;
        }

        tmp = list->head;
        next = tmp->next;

        printf("%s: Dequeueing %d\n", __FUNCTION__,tmp->num);
        list->head = next;
        list->total_elem--;
        free(tmp);
}
void print_list(list_t *list)
{
        node_t *tmp;

        if (!list->head) {
                printf("%s: queue empty \n", __FUNCTION__);
        }

        tmp = list->head;

        while (tmp) {
                printf("%d ", tmp->num);
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:    prodcon

prodcon:        list.o prod_consume.o
        gcc -g -o prodcon list.o prod_consume.o -lpthread

list.o: list.c list.h
        gcc -g -c -o list.o list.c

prod_consume.o: prod_consume.c list.h
        gcc -g -c -o prod_consume.o prod_consume.c

clean:
        rm -f *.o ./prodcon
```

Note that if I un-comment pthread_mutex_lock and unlock calls in printer fn, the program runs without a crash on MacOS, as expected. But on Linux, even without un-commenting those lines in printer thread, it runs fine.

So my question. Is thread scheduling different in Linux. Or is is there some other reason?

Any reason the program runs fine on Linux, while it crahes on MacOS?

Comment: It dumps core for me on CentOS 9.  Perhaps you've just been lucky.

Comment: Originally I had tried on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. GCP doesn't give me the ability to have CentOS 9, but Debian 10 also seems to have no problem.

Comment: I was able to finally get a CentOS 9 VM on GCP and indeed it crashed in a few seconds just like it does on MacOS. Looking at "uname -a" output on CentOS 9 I see: "Linux instance-7 5.14.0-183.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 31 09:18:51 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux" whereas on Ubuntu I see "Linux instance-3 5.15.0-1025-gcp #32~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 29 08:31:04 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". Does that "PREEMPT_DYNAMIC" have anything to do with it?

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks a ton for verifying on CenOS and indeed as I pointed out I found the same behaviour on CentOS. I noticed that it has the extra "PREEMPT_DYNAMIC" in it's uname -a output. The other thing I noticed that if you run the program with "taskset -c 1 ./prodcon," it no longer crashes. Basically the argument 1 here means that the task should be run on cpu core 1 only. So it leads me to "suspect" that crash happens when the threads are scheduled on different cpu and end-up accessing the shared data. When they are forced to run on 1 CPU alone, the crash was not seen (at least not so far).

Answer (score 0):

```
//lines deliberately commented out to show the crash
```

The `print_list` accesses the list without the lock; *of course* the code will intermittently crash, what did you expect?

> on Linux, even without un-commenting those lines in printer thread, it runs fine.

It doesn't "run fine" -- it exercises undefined behavior, and *will* crash if you run enough times and the stars align to expose the data race.

Comment: No, there is more to it. As I reported, it has something to do with PREEMPT_DYNAMIC being not there on the Ubuntu as opposed to CentOS, where the behaviour is same as MacOS. FYI ran it enough times and long enough and still didn't crash on a linux kernel which doesn't have "PREEMPT_DYNAMIC" in its "uname -a" output.

Comment: @HarperDada "No, there is more to it" -- no, there _isn't_. If your program exercises undefined behavior (as yours does), _all bets are off_.

Comment: Nobody is debating that the program should not crash. Question is why it doesn't crash on some systems. You are saying if I run it long enough, it will crash. I am telling you I let it run all night and it didn't crash. So the behavior is very unexpected. And it's better to investigate if the KERNEL configuration can make a difference.

Comment: "Question is why it doesn't crash ..." -- it's a _stupid_ question to ask. It didn't crash because timing didn't align quite right, and because you didn't try it enough times. It may crash tomorrow, or on a slightly faster processor, or for a million other reasons. You don't seem to understand what undefined behavior is -- it's not guaranteed to crash your program, but you better _not_ exercise it (unless you like random crashes).